# Pegar hora do array mais próxima a hora atual

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Possuo o seguinte Json:

```
{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0.0055,
"cnt": 40,
"list": [
    {
        "dt": 1560319200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 15.15,
            "temp_min": 14.49,
            "temp_max": 15.15,
            "pressure": 1021.11,
            "sea_level": 1021.11,
            "grnd_level": 995.76,
            "humidity": 96,
            "temp_kf": 0.66
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "céu pouco nublado",
                "icon": "02n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 19
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.78,
            "deg": 246.743
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560330000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 14.69,
            "temp_min": 14.19,
            "temp_max": 14.69,
            "pressure": 1020.69,
            "sea_level": 1020.69,
            "grnd_level": 995.4,
            "humidity": 95,
            "temp_kf": 0.5
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "céu pouco nublado",
                "icon": "02n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 17
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.7,
            "deg": 256.122
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 09:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560340800,
        "main": {
            "temp": 19.68,
            "temp_min": 19.35,
            "temp_max": 19.68,
            "pressure": 1021.93,
            "sea_level": 1021.93,
            "grnd_level": 996.86,
            "humidity": 74,
            "temp_kf": 0.33
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 801,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "céu pouco nublado",
                "icon": "02d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 23
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.26,
            "deg": 210.741
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560351600,
        "main": {
            "temp": 25.72,
            "temp_min": 25.55,
            "temp_max": 25.72,
            "pressure": 1020.78,
            "sea_level": 1020.78,
            "grnd_level": 995.84,
            "humidity": 55,
            "temp_kf": 0.17
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nuvens dispersas",
                "icon": "03d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 36
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 1.34,
            "deg": 72.064
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 15:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560362400,
        "main": {
            "temp": 25.68,
            "temp_min": 25.68,
            "temp_max": 25.68,
            "pressure": 1018.44,
            "sea_level": 1018.44,
            "grnd_level": 993.46,
            "humidity": 59,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nuvens dispersas",
                "icon": "03d"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 47
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 2.12,
            "deg": 81.239
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "d"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560373200,
        "main": {
            "temp": 18.45,
            "temp_min": 18.45,
            "temp_max": 18.45,
            "pressure": 1019.96,
            "sea_level": 1019.96,
            "grnd_level": 994.89,
            "humidity": 97,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 802,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nuvens dispersas",
                "icon": "03n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 25
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.93,
            "deg": 76.605
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 21:00:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": 1560384000,
        "main": {
            "temp": 17.25,
            "temp_min": 17.25,
            "temp_max": 17.25,
            "pressure": 1021.66,
            "sea_level": 1021.66,
            "grnd_level": 996.24,
            "humidity": 97,
            "temp_kf": 0
        },
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "nuvens quebradas",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ],
        "clouds": {
            "all": 59
        },
        "wind": {
            "speed": 0.68,
            "deg": 309.784
        },
        "sys": {
            "pod": "n"
        },
        "dt_txt": "2019-06-13 00:00:00"
    }
],
"city": {
    "id": 3459712,
    "name": "Joinville",
    "coord": {
        "lat": -26.3045,
        "lon": -48.8487
    },
    "country": "BR",
    "population": 461304,
    "timezone": -10800
  }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar a informação do array que esteja mais próxima da hora atual, sendo que o array trás a informação de 3 em 3 horas.

Ex: "dt_txt": "2019-06-12 12:00:00", está mais próximo a 12:42(Agora) do que as 15:00 horas:

Já possuo o objeto organizado:

```
var result = weather.list.Select(x => new { day = x.dt_txt,
                        tempMax = x.main.MaximumTemperature,
                        tempMin = x.main.MinimumTemperature,
                        Hum = x.main.Humidity}).OrderBy(x => x.day);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você converter a string para o DateTime, pode calcular a diferença entre a data do registro e a atual usando `Math.Abs()` no `OrderBy()` e pegar o primeiro resultado.

```
var result = weather.list.Select(x => new { day = DateTime.Parse(x.dt_txt),
                                            tempMax = x.main.MaximumTemperature,
                                            tempMin = x.main.MinimumTemperature,
                                            Hum = x.main.Humidity
                                 })
                                 .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.day.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks))
                                 .FirstOrDefault();
```